# How to match array

Tags: javascript

What would be the best approach to check if all the elements of a given array are contained by another array? For example:

```
match(['countryaarea', 'countrybarea'], ['countrya', 'countryb']) // true
```

I have tried `indexOf()` and `includes()`, but it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show us what you've tried and we can help you find a solution.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output

Comment: Have you read the [MDN JavaScript documentation?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) methods.

```js
const arr = ['countryaarea', 'countrybarea'];

function match(array, searchArray) {
  if (array.length !== searchArray.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return array.every(el => searchArray.some(sEl => el.includes(sEl)));
}

console.log(match(arr, ['countrya', 'countryb'])); // returns true
console.log(match(arr, ['countrya'])) // returns false
console.log(match(arr, ['abcd'])) // returns false
console.log(match(arr, [])) // returns false
```

You would also want to check for null values.

Answer (score 1):

**... best approach...**

The 'best approach' is robust code that handles edge cases. But the OP is insufficient to know what the edge cases are. That's addressed below but first, the code.

```
function isSubset ( subset, reference ) {
  if ( !Array.isArray( subset ) || !Array.isArray( reference )) return false;

  return subset.every( element => reference.includes( element ));
}
```

The 'best approach' for coding:

- generally almost never involves `for` loops. Less readable and more error prone than Iterator functions. And as seen in the other answers, `for` loops put artificial constraints on the problem.
- Code composition using functions is in keeping with Javascript language design, *functional programming* paradigm, OO principles, and clean code in general.

The 'best approach' depends on desired functionality:

- Must the arrays be the same length? All answers (as of this writing) assumes that.
- Must the test-array be shorter and/or equal length of the reference array?
- Can either or both arrays have duplicate items?
- Is this throw-away code ?
- Is this destined for a library or at least production code?
- What if there are mixed types in either or both arrays?
- If this is simply "git er done", isolated use then verbose-but-understood code is OK and non-robust parameter checking is OK.

---

**My assumptions**

- Return false for failed parameter checks, don't just blow up.
- Both things must be arrays.
- No constraints on array length.
- Duplicate elements in either array do not need item-for-item duplication in the other.
- An empty array is a subset of any other array including another empty array.
- String compare is case sensitive.

I did not want to get wrapped around the axle with using "truthiness" for parameter validation so I left that sleeping demon alone.

---

Answer (score 0):

```
var arraysMatch = function (arr1, arr2) {

    // Check if the arrays are the same length
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;

    // Check if all items exist and are in the same order
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
    }

    // Otherwise, return true
    return true;

};
```

Comment: You would need to sort the arrays first for this approach to work.